# Referencing methods of one JFrame from another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am using the visual editor in NetBeans to create a GUI for a calendar app. I have one JFrame (Main) that instantiates another JFrame (Output) and in doing so passes a reference of itself into Output's constructor.

```
public void output(ArrayList<Appointment> a) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Output(main, a).setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Output constructer:

```
public Output(Main m, ArrayList<Appointment> app) {
        initComponents();
        main = m;
        appointments = app;
        for (Appointment a : appointments) {
            list.addElement(a.toString());
        }
        outputList.setModel(list);
    }
```

However, when I try to run this method of the Output JFrame:

```
if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Delete appointment?") == 0) {
            list.remove(outputList.getSelectedIndex());
            main.diary.delete(appointments.get(outputList.getSelectedIndex()));
            main.setDays();
            if (list.isEmpty()) {
                dispose();
            }
            outputList.setModel(list);
        }
```

I get the following error: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 1"

As you can see I reference a method (setDays()) and an object (diary) of the Main JFrame class.

Is it because I am creating a new instance of Main when I invoke Output's constructor?

Sorry, I am fairly new to Java and still have a lot to learn. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Basically there are less than a handful of ways to create new instances of things (`new ...` being chief among them), and you haven't used _any_ of those in your `Output` constructor.  So this certainly has nothing to do with any new instance of `Main`, and it _might_ not have anything to do with `main` or `main.diary` at all. Check the stack traceback that came with the error message to find out exactly  where in your code the error came from.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Ok, I had a look at the call stack and the last item says EventDispatchThread.run:90. When I click on it I see the code: "pumpEvents(new Conditional() {". Further up there's EventQueue.dispatchEvent:742, ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege:85, EventQueue$5.run:743. Not sure how to make sense of all that.

Comment: It sounds like you're working from the wrong (i.e., less useful) end of the traceback.  Start from the actual error message (`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:...`) and work your way back from that and you should start seeing references to your code fairly quickly.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I do apologise, it looks like it was a really simple error after all. I forgot that my 'outputList' actually references 'list' and so when I did 'list.remove(outputList.getSelectedIndex());' followed by 'outputList.getSelectedIndex()' it was passing -1 causing an out of bounds exception when looking for that index in a similar array. After reordering some code my program now works. Thanks again for your replies!

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)